# I encountered error upon populating the datagrid from sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, datagrid, csom

I encountered error in populating the datagrid with Sharepoint list data, Im not sure it is becuase of the SPClient.ListItem.

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException: 'The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.'

```
            if (collObj.Count != 0) 
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dRow;

                DataColumn dcID = new DataColumn("Id");
                dcID.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                DataColumn dcTitle = new DataColumn("Title");
                dcTitle.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");



                dt.Columns.Add(dcID);
                dt.Columns.Add(dcTitle);

                foreach (SPClient.ListItem item in collObj)
                {
                    dRow = dt.NewRow();
                    dRow["Id"] = item.Id;
                    dRow["Title"] = item["item"];
                    dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: (SPClient.ListItem item in collObj)
                {
                    dRow = dt.NewRow();
                    dRow["Id"] = item.Id;
                    dRow["Title"] = item["item"];
                    dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't load the collObj items properly.
It is not in the code so I am only assuming.
Try loading the items that you need, something like this

```
context.Load(collObj, items => items.Include(i => i.Id, i => i.item));
context.ExecuteQuery();
```